# Append to a Func in LINQ

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, func

I have a method with a projection

```
public IQueryable<EmpDTO> GetEmployee(Func<Employee, EmpDTO> projection = null)
{
    if(projection == null)
        projection = emp => new EmpDTO {
                                  Id = emp.Id,
                                  Name = emp.Name,
                                  Salary = emp.Salary,    
                                };
    return entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Salary > 10000).Select(projection);
}
```

It can be extended as follows:

```
query = classInstance.GetEmployee(emp => new EmpDTO {
                                          Id = emp.Id,
                                          Name = emp.Name,
                                          Salary = emp.Salary,    
                                          Address = emp.Address
                                      });
```

> How can I APPEND only the "Address" field to the Func without
>   rewriting the entire fields (repeated fields Id, Name, Salary)

Comment: You can't do that with `Func`.

Comment: are you looking to use expression<func<tEntity,bool>> ?

Comment: You would want to use `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` instead of just `Func`. But it's going to require using an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a whole new expression tree with one additional expression in the initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Expression`, you can build a new lambda to initialize the fields:

```
public IQueryable<EmpDTO> GetEmployee(Expression<Func<Employee, EmpDTO>> addProj = null) {
    Expression<Func<Employee, EmpDTO>> projection = emp => new EmpDTO {
        Id = emp.Id,
        Name = emp.Name,
        Salary = emp.Salary,
    };

    if (addProj != null) {
        var pBody = ((MemberInitExpression)projection.Body);
        var newBindings = new ReadOnlyCollection<MemberBinding>(pBody.Bindings.Concat(((MemberInitExpression)addProj.Body).Bindings).ToList());
        var newBody = Expression.MemberInit(pBody.NewExpression, newBindings);
        projection = (Expression<Func<Employee, EmpDTO>>) Expression.Lambda(newBody, projection.Parameters);
    }

    return entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Salary > 10000).Select(projection);
}
```

You could also build the entire lambda from scratch, but that seemed like more work to me. Plus you can encapsulate the combine init logic into an extension method:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> Add<TIn, TOut>(this Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> proj, Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> addProj = null) {
    if (addProj != null) {
        var pBody = ((MemberInitExpression)proj.Body);
        var newBindings = new ReadOnlyCollection<MemberBinding>(pBody.Bindings.Concat(((MemberInitExpression)addProj.Body).Bindings).ToList());
        var newBody = Expression.MemberInit(pBody.NewExpression, newBindings);
        proj = (Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>>)Expression.Lambda(newBody, proj.Parameters);
    }

    return proj;
}
```

which reduces the `GetEmployee` body to:

```
public IQueryable<EmpDTO> GetEmployee(Expression<Func<Employee, EmpDTO>> addProj = null) {
    Expression<Func<Employee, EmpDTO>> projection = emp => new EmpDTO {
        Id = emp.Id,
        Name = emp.Name,
        Salary = emp.Salary,
    };

    if (addProj != null)
        projection = projection.Add(addProj);

    return entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Salary > 10000).Select(projection);
}
```